# how do I fix this key signing error in google play console?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console

So I just built the new version of my app but when I upload the apk to the google play console I get this error

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDNbO.png)

I have no idea what's causing it. I checked and within unity the key is the same one I used the first time I built the app. ID is same from the keystore. I have no idea what's causing this or how to fix it so i'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You must the **same** signing key used to sign the app bundle when it was **initially** uploaded to the Google Play Store. This signing key is typically stored in a Keystore file, which you can use to sign the app bundle using the `jarsigner` tool.

Comment: yes, but it is the same key within unity. It's the exact same one I used, and I can't figure out why it's not working

Comment: Same keystore file you used to sign the first upload?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Alias]

You should use choose the same Project Key Alias of the Keystore.